# Google Translate module randomly throws "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType"

Tags: python, module, google-translate, googletrans

I use Google Translate in Python and found this bug in my code. I copy here a minimal reproducible example:

```
import time

from googletrans import Translator as google_Translator

class Translator:
    lang: str
    def __init__(self, lang: str  = 'en'):
        self.lang = lang

    def go(self, text: str):
        try:
            translator = google_Translator()
        except Exception as e:
            print("First exception type: ", e)
            print("Argument: ", text)
            print("lang: ", self.lang)
            print("translator: ", translator)
            return None

        try:
            t1 = translator.translate(text, dest=self.lang)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Second exception type: ", e)
            print("Argument: '%s'" % text)
            print("lang: ", self.lang)
            print("translator: ", translator)
            return None

        try:
            t2 = t1.text
        except Exception as e:
            print("Third exception type: ", e)
            print("argument: ", text)
            print("lang: ", self.lang)
            print("translator: ", translator)
            return None

        return t2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Translator('English')
    while True:
        print("\n---\n%s\n---\n" % t.go('Mieux Comprendre, Mieux Décider, Mieux Soigner'))
        time.sleep(5)
```

Sometimes the code works and translates the sentence, other times it does not. Here's sample output:

```
---
Better understand, decide better, better care
---


---
Better understand, decide better, better care
---


---
Better understand, decide better, better care
---


---
Better understand, decide better, better care
---

Second exception type:  the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
Argument: 'Mieux Comprendre, Mieux Décider, Mieux Soigner'
lang:  English
translator:  <googletrans.client.Translator object at 0x109e96d40>

---
None
---


---
Better understand, decide better, better care
---
```

Here are my system specifications:

```
(venv)$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.11
(venv)$ python3 -m pip show googletrans
Name: googletrans
Version: 4.0.0rc1
Summary: Free Google Translate API for Python. Translates totally free of charge.
Home-page: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans
Author: SuHun Han
Author-email: ssut@ssut.me
License: MIT
Location: ~/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: httpx
Required-by:
```

Why does it behave like this, and how to fix it?

### update

The exception thrown is often `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType`. If the text only has spaces, it also sometimes throws `IndexError: list index out of range`. Here is the stacktrace for the latter.

```
TypeError from translator:  list index out of range
Text =  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Translator.py", line 22, in go
    return translator.translate(text, dest=self.lang).text
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 222, in translate
    translated_parts = list(map(lambda part: TranslatedPart(part[0], part[1] if len(part) >= 2 else []), parsed[1][0][0][5]))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 222, in <lambda>
    translated_parts = list(map(lambda part: TranslatedPart(part[0], part[1] if len(part) >= 2 else []), parsed[1][0][0][5]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'll add the stacktrace of the former when I see it.

Comment: My inital thought here is that since you're translating the same string over and over and ergo the string itself isn't causing the problem, it might be on the google translate API end. Maybe there's a threshold of how many reqeusts you can submit within a certain timeframe and it's throwing an error// returning None instead of the translation?

Comment: Yes, that's very possible. For now, I'm catching these exceptions and retrying after a delay, and that seems to work.

Comment: Were you able to see what exception exactly is getting thrown?

Comment: Yes, I added the error type and a stacktrace in the question.